# Java directory pathway

Tags: java, directory, path, javac, openbsd

I wanted to start learning Java but I am a bit confused as to how to set the path correctly. I want to make a directory in my home directory for all my java programs so I was thinking something like:

```
/home/user/Java_Projects
```

but I'm not sure how to make the symbolic link to it. Would it be something like this?:

```
ln -sf /usr/local/jdk-11/bin/java /usr/local/bin/java/Java_Projects
```

Also, in this case what happens with `javac`? Does it then become:

```
ln -sf /usr/local/jdk-11/bin/javac /usr/local/bin/javac/Java_Projects
```

A strange thing that I've noticed is that when I run the code in my home directory (`/home/user`) everything works fine but then when I try to run the code from my java directory by changing to `/home/user/Java_Projects` it won't work anymore and I have no idea why.

The only thing I can think of is some kind of permission error because this is what I get:

> error: error while writing HelloWorld: /home/user/Java_Projects/HelloWorld.class

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing the JDK tools (java, javac, etc) with the coding side.  You will need to add `/usr/local/jdk-11/bin` to your PATH environment variable.  Since you're in a Unix based environment you'll want to add that in your `.bashrc` or the equivalent for your shell.  Something like:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/jdk-11/bin:$PATH
```

You normally have to start a new shell (i.e. the command line window) or log out and back in for that to take effect.  Then, in your `Java_projects` directory you can simply run:

```
javac HelloWorld.java
```

You should have write permission in the `Java_projects` already assuming that it's in your home directory.  If not, run `chmod 755 Java_projects` from the `/home/user` directory.  The `user` in this case should be your login name to the operating system.

Comment: Thank you. Now it makes sense!

Comment: Can you accept the answer then @davidgarcia?  Thanks!